# What is a Coalescent Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Coalescent Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Coalescent Words™ | Not Coalescent Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| AGHAST | UNSURPRISED |
| ALABAMA | MISSISSIPPI |
| BASS | TREBLE |
| BLACK | WHITE |
| JUSTIFIED | UNWARRANTED |
| MADAME | MONSIEUR |
| PROCESSED | NATURAL |
| RUST | OXIDIZE |
| STONED | SOBER |
| SUPPORT | SABOTAGE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Coalescent Words™,Not Coalescent Words™
AGHAST,UNSURPRISED
ALABAMA,MISSISSIPPI
BASS,TREBLE
BLACK,WHITE
JUSTIFIED,UNWARRANTED
MADAME,MONSIEUR
PROCESSED,NATURAL
RUST,OXIDIZE
STONED,SOBER
SUPPORT,SABOTAGE
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Coalescent Word™ without relying on the other words. These are not the only examples of Coalescent Words™.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Coalescent words satisfy the property that

> Each letter in the word is either repeated in the word or the word contains one of its alphabetical neighbours.

Example

> If we sort the letters of JUSTIFIED we get DEFIIJSTU which has three groups of neighbouring letters, (DEF)(IIJ)(STU), and no letter is alphabetically isolated. 
>  On the other hand if we sort the letters of UNWARRANTED we get AADENNRRTUW in which 'W' is not repeated and does not have an alphabetical neighbour within the word.